# Number of OpenCL compute units in a multikernel implementation

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, opencl

I am working in a multikernel OpenCL implementation and I am not sure how different kernels map into compute units.

All my kernels execute concurrently and I think that only workgroups executing the same kernel are assigned to a single compute unit. So I deduce  I have at least one compute unit for every different kernel I use. Am I right?

I know that I can use clGetDeviceInfo and look in the field CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, but it does not tell me how the kernels are distributed or how many compute units I am using.

And related to this question, if I do not specify how many compute units are going to be used with "**attribute**((num_compute_units(X)))", how many are used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For most OpenCL work you can safely ignore the number of compute units. Also, if you plan to run on different kinds of hardware, you really *should* ignore it. For kernels that use shared local memory you *will* need to worry about maximum work group sizes, but that's a different thing. In that case you can code to the minimum across the hardware you plan to support, or write flexible kernels that can handle any workgroup size.